# Finding the splitting field of the polynomial $x^5+2x^4+5x^2+x+4$ over $F_{11}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I am working on the following problem:

Find the splitting field of the polynomial $f(x)=x^5+2x^4+5x^2+x+4$ over $F_{11}$.

What I have done:
So far I found that $-2$ is the only root of $f(x)$ in $F_{11}$. I have also factored $f(x)$ as $f(x)=(x+2)(x^2+5x+1)(x^2-5x+2)$ over $F_{11}$.

Apparently the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F_{11}$ is $F_{11^4}$. Can someone help me understand how one can conclude that.

Comment: The splitting field is $F_{11^2}$ because irreducible quadratics generate the same field, since there is only one finite field of size each prime power.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial $x^2+5x+1$ has no roots in $F_{11}$: indeed
$$
x^2+5x+1=x^2-6x+9-8=(x-3)^2-8
$$
and $8$ is not a square modulo $11$.

Similarly, $x^2-5x+2=x^2+6x+9-7=(x+3)^2-7$ and $7$ is not a square modulo $11$.

Adding a root of $x^2+5x+1$ is the same as adding a square root of $2$. The elements are of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$, and we must look whether $7$ is a square here: try and solve
$$
(a+b\sqrt{2})^2=7
$$
and you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

We are considering the field $F_{11}(\alpha,\beta)$ were $\alpha^2 + 5\alpha +1=0$ and $\beta^2 - 5\beta +2=0$. We are going to show that $$F_{11}(\alpha,\beta)=F_{11}(\alpha+\beta)$$

In fact summing the equations we get $$(\alpha + \beta)(\alpha - \beta + 5)=1$$ which means that these elements are inverse one another, thus adding $(\alpha + \beta)$ to the base field we add its inverse $(\alpha - \beta + 5)$ as well, and also their sum and their difference and thus both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. We proved the claim. Now notice that $(\alpha + \beta) = \frac{\sqrt{21}+\sqrt{17}}{2}$ simply solving the equations of degree two. It has minimum polynomial $x^4 -19x^2+1$. It can be factorized in $F_{11}$ as $x^4 -19x^2+1=(x^2+5)(x^2-2)$ thus $\alpha + \beta$ is a solution of one of them, let's call it $p(x)$. So $$F_{11}(\alpha,\beta)=F_{11}(\alpha+\beta)\simeq\frac{F_{11}[x]}{(p(x))}$$

Comment: In $F_{11}$, we have that $x^4+3x^2+1$ factors as $(x^2+5)(x^2-2)$.

Comment: @JoeyZou Unfortunately I can't see where is the mistake :(

Comment: @JoeyZou I mean $\alpha + \beta $ is not a solution of these two polynomials so I'm quite confused!

Comment: Actually, $\left(\frac{\sqrt{21}+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4}(21+17+2\sqrt{21}\cdot\sqrt{17}) = \frac{1}{2}(19+\sqrt{21}\cdot\sqrt{17})$. Now $(\sqrt{21}\sqrt{17})^2 = 21\cdot 17 = -1\cdot 6 = 5$, and in $F_{11}$ there already exist two elements whose square is $5$; namely $4$ and $-4$. So either $(\alpha+\beta)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(19+4) = \frac{1}{2}(23) = \frac{1}{2}(12) = 6 = -5$, or $(\alpha+\beta)^2 = \frac{1}{2}(19-4) = \frac{1}{2}(15) = \frac{1}{2}(4) = 2$. Thus, $\alpha+\beta$ is a root of either $x^2+5$ or $x^2-2$.

Comment: @JoeyZou Thank you very much!!